# What’s the most idiomatic way to implement a “floating tag” in Git?

Tags: git

I keep my website in a Git repository. It’s just a small personal site so there’s no fancy automation; I’ll make a bunch of changes and then periodically push the site to the server using [jekyll-s3](https://github.com/versapay/jekyll-s3). I do like to keep track of which revisions have been uploaded and which haven’t, and right now I have a branch called `pushed` into which I merge `master` each time I upload to the server. (If any other branches are involved I merge everything into `master` before pushing, so that only `master` ever gets merged into `pushed`.)

This works well enough, but it seems weird to me to be using an “entire” branch when all I care about is marking one commit at a time as “this has been pushed”. (Yes, I know that branches are considered very lightweight in Git.) Terminology-wise it seems like I want to “tag” the latest commit each time I upload to the server—except that in Git, a tag is supposed to be an immutable reference to one specific commit. Is keeping a branch called `pushed` the most idiomatic way to do what I’m trying to do, or is there a better way?

Comment: A branch is just a pointer to a commit. Nothing more. You can't really have anything "more lightweight".

Comment: Did you know that when you push, you push all your local commits and not just the last one?

Comment: @Shahbaz Sure. What I want to keep track of is the most recent commit that has been pushed. (When I say “push” I mean that I’m just uploading some files via FTP or whatever; I’m not actually using `git push` to update a remote repository.) Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yeah I see. Read my answer. It's not exactly what you said in your comment, but more or less tells you you are doing the right thing.

Comment: In some version control systems/workflows a "floating tag" is something like "All-Tests-Pass".  Which itself is versioned, e.g. "All-Tests-Pass--BRANCH-foo-DATE-...".  i.e. "floating" means default, typically most recent, version of that tag/predicate.  NOTE:  you cannot assume that all tests pass on any particular branch, even if you keep master clean. //  This usage of "floating tag"  is incompatible with git's  preference for tags to be immutable. // Different terminology reflecting different backgrounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to have a reference to your last update on the website, right? Well, branching is in fact what they do, but not with the naming you have done.

As you may know, there are two major ways for development with version control systems:

- `master` is development branch. In this case, the stable releases are certain tags.
- `master` is the stable branch. In this case, you have other branches for development. When you want to add your feature to `master`, you merge master with your own branch and test it. If it worked, you merge the results with `master` and push it to your website.

What you are talking about is in fact the second method, where you have a stable branch named `pushed` and you keep it stable (uploaded, working, whatever property you want) at all times.

So, yeah what you do already exists, however more idiomatically, they keep `master` as that stable branch rather than some other branch (for example named `pushed`). It's the same concept though.

**Edit:** What I'm saying is that, whenever you want to upload your changes to your website, merge whatever you have in `master` (or `pushed` if you like), and then upload it. This way, the last commit of `master` (or `pushed`) is the last upload of the website.

Comment: Actually, I am familiar (from [this wonderful document](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)) with the strategy of keeping `master` as a stable branch and only merging into it during the release process. For whatever reason I never thought to apply it to this website case. I think I’ll stick with this general sort of strategy (although it seems like tags could work fine as well).

Comment: Nice link! You are absolutely right, there is more than one way to achieve what you want, you should just pick one you like better!

Answer (score 4):

Tags in Git come in two flavours: "lightweight" and "annotated". A lightweight tag is very much like a branch head, it is just a name that points to a specific commit and nothing more. It's straightforward to change the commit id that a lightweight tag points to.

An annotated tag has its own sha1 id, timestamp, committer, description, optionally a signature, and also points to a specific commit. I think this is the kind of tag you're referring to when you say "supposed to be an immutable reference".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git tag -f tagName`.

I'm not a git expert, but I don't see a reason why you shouldn't use a tag to do that. A branch is really lightweight though, but tags will save the merging.

Comment: But the merge should always be a fast-forward "merge".  Really, a moving tag *is* a branch.

Comment: The problem with moving tags around is that Git workspaces that already have the tag won't be updated with the new location of the tag unless the local tag is deleted first. If you're not careful you suddently have _N_ different opinions of what a tag points to, even for workspaces that have been synced at the same time with no intervening changes and therefore intuitively should point to the same commit.