# Does Git Support "Copy To" a Tag?

Tags: git

I think this question requires a bit of background, as there may be a better way to do this in git.

I have a build server that does continuous integration for our main development branch.  This works great, and is obviously always looking for changes and building that specific branch.

I also have a QA build, that we want to build and deploy on demand.  In the past, when I used SVN, we would create a tag called "QA", which we would simply copy the correct revision to when we wanted to deploy a QA build.  We would re-use the QA tag, and this allowed us to point the build configuration at this tag.

What I want to avoid is having to change the build configuration when it comes time to deploy QA.  A branch doesn't "feel" like the right answer for this.

How would I achieve this in git without incurring a lot of process overhead?

Comment: I [asked a similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288073/whats-the-most-idiomatic-way-to-implement-a-floating-tag-in-git) a couple of years ago. To summarize the discussion, a branch is probably the most idiomatic Git way to do it, even though it might seem weird at first.

Comment: The (only? main?) reason to "copy to" a tag in SVN is that SVN branches—and its tags are just branches, according to the SVN book at least—are quite heavy-weight; it's expensive to make a new branch or tag.  Git's branches and tags "weigh" almost nothing (annotated tags, which enable things like PGP-signing, are heavier but still feathers compared to SVN branches).  In git, you can think of a branch as an automatically-moving tag: tags are static, branches move (forward, normally).  So a branch is the "right" answer here, in as much as anything can be called "right".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [bdesham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371228/bdesham): if you push the right commit to a dedicated QA branch, your build scheduler can monitor that branch and be sure to build against the right commit (the last one pushed to that QA branch).