# Complete Merge/Copy/Push of a Branch

Tags: git

As part of a build process, I need to essentially make one branch look exactly like another.  It needs to be an actual branch (tagging is not an option).

Both branches will already exist.  The Destination branch will never be touched by anything other than this process.

This is what I have:

```
git checkout Destination
git merge Source
git push
```

Does this look like a good approach?  Is there a simpler way?

**Edit**

To clarify, the end goal would be to take a snapshot of Source and push it to the remote as Destination. We would do this each time a specific build was run.

Comment: By "look exactly like", do you mean that the contents of the working directory when you check out either of the two heads of branches should be identical, or that, in addition to that, the same needs to be true for each successive commit on the branch back to the origin of the branch? I tend to think of the first case as the branch heads being identical, while the second would be the entire branch being identical. They're two completely different things...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's the former--the branch heads.  Basically I want to "copy" Dev => QA at a point in time for a build.  Based on my experience doing this with SVN, I asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615529/does-git-support-copy-to-a-tag.  However, tags aren't an option for other reasons as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to essentially make one branch look exactly like another.

```
git branch -f one_branch another
```

Now `one_branch` looks exactly like `another`.  If you want to have `one_branch` checked out locally as well, replace `branch -f` with `checkout -B`.

Comment: Interesting.  Follow branch -f with git push?  Any downsides to this approach vs. what I have in my question?

Comment: Yes to the first, to the second, your method doesn't make the two branches identical unless one_branch was already an ancestor of another -- in which case the branch -f/checkout -B achieves exactly the same result without the rigmarole.

Answer (score 0):

So if you need the exact state why you don't use the Source branch on your destination System?

We use the **master** Branch for production and a **dev** Branch for the test system. On the daily work we work with feature branches. So you make a new branch from the **master** branch work on it and merge the feature branch in the **maste** and **dev** branch.

In this case you should never merge the **dev** in the **master** branch. With this szenatio you have the abillity to put your feature branch first on the dev and test the feature. After that you merge the feature branch in the **master** and put it live.

Here is a good tutorial with merge strategies.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/git-branches#!merge

If you really need the exact state its better if you make a hard reset to the **source** branch. Then you can be sure that its really the same.

Comment: We essentially need a snapshop of the Source branch, or a checkpoint.  Similar to a tag, but we don't want to use a tag (for good reasons).

Comment: I should clarify--we also want to push this snapshot/checkpoint to the remote.

Comment: The problem is if you need a snapshot its better to create a new branch as snapshot otherwise you will overwrite the old state. So perhaps its a solution to create a new branch with a prefix something like 'snap_tagname'. Then you could write a script wich manage these snapshots and cleanup old branches.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  We would be merging Source => Destination each time.  We want this destination branch to be a periodic snapshot of the source, so "overwriting" it is really what we want.

Comment: Its not really clear whats the goal of you question. So in then you can merge it. Or make a reset the the source branch. Then you can be sure that its the exact state without conflicts.

Comment: I added some clarification to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new commit on the tip of `my_branch` that has exactly the same contents as the tip of `other_branch`, here's one way to do that:

```
$ git checkout my_branch                        # make sure we are on the branch we want to add to
$ git rm -rf .                                  # remove everything belonging to current tip
$ git archive other_branch | tar xf -           # replace with the contents of other_branch tip
$ git add -A .                                  # stage all the modifications
$ git commit -m "updated to other_branch"       # commit the changes
```

If you're on Windows and don't have `tar` available, the `git archive` step may need to look more like `git archive --format=zip other_branch | unzip ...` - I don't use Windows' `unzip` often enough to remember the appropriate options, and you might have a different unzipper, like `winzip` or something, so the exact command may need some adjusting. But the basic process should stay the same...

Your approach with `git merge` is valid, but may not produce exactly the results you want, since it creates a new commit that contains the changes made on both branches merged together (hence the name...), and so it isn't really a snapshot. The above takes a snapshot of the current tip of `other_branch` and adds that as a new commit on the top of `my_branch`, and would be appropriate for example if you are building a side branch that contains only release snapshots, or other specific milestone-type commits without all the intermediate commits.

You might also be able to achieve this with a `git merge -s ours --squash` or something, followed by moving branch pointers around, but I tend to think the above is at least conceptually easier to follow.